# Flat File to XML Grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I have a flat file I would like to transform to XML using XSLT.
The first character of each line represents a block of information and I would like to group everything together.
The lines can begin with multiple characters.  What I want to do is group blocks of lines together that are in between the character `1`.

Here is what the input file looks like:

```
0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The `x` just represents data in the line that I can take care of.
What I am looking to do is product this:

```
<Root>
    <Header> // O line
    </Header>
    <Summary id="xxxxx"> // First 1 line
        <data_from_2>
        </data_from_2>
        <data_from_3>
        </data_from_3>
        <data_from_5>
        </data_from_5>
        <data_from_8>
        </data_from_8>
    </Summary>
    <Summary id="xxxxx"> // Second 1 line
        <data_from_2>
        </data_from_2>
        <data_from_3>
        </data_from_3>
        <data_from_5>
        </data_from_5>
        <data_from_8>
        </data_from_8>
    </Summary>
    <Summary id="xxxxx"> // Third 1 line
        <data_from_2>
        </data_from_2>
        <data_from_3>
        </data_from_3>
        <data_from_5>
        </data_from_5>
        <data_from_8>
        </data_from_8>
    </Summary>
    <Footer> // 9 line
    </Footer>
</Root>
```

The hard part is that it is not known how many lines will be under the `1` line.
There could be just one line to group under it or many more lines.

Here is my initial XSLT (It currently produces a flat structure):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#x0A;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="tab" select="'&#x09;'" />

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            <FirstData>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>

                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\r?\n')">
                    <!-- DETERMINE WHAT FIRST CHAR LOOKS LIKE -->
                    <xsl:variable name="lineToken" select="substring(., 1, 1)"/>

                    <!-- HEADER -->
                    <xsl:if test="$lineToken='0'">
                        <xsl:variable name="periodStart" select="substring(., 2, 6)"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><HEADER><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><Period_start_date><xsl:sequence select="$periodStart"/></Period_start_date><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/></HEADER><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                    </xsl:if>


                    <!-- SUMMARY -->
                    <xsl:if test="$lineToken='1'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><xsl:element name="SUMMARY">
                        <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select ="substring(., 2, 11)"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="ID" select="substring(., 2, 11)"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="batchDate" select="substring(., 13, 4)"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><ID><xsl:sequence select="$fdmsMerchantNum"/></FDMS_Merchant_Number><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><Batch_Date><xsl:sequence select="$batchDate"/></Batch_Date><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/></xsl:element><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <!-- Data 2 -->
                    <xsl:if test="$lineToken='2'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><Data_2><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="Sales" select="substring(., 2, 3)"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><Sales><xsl:sequence select="$Sales"/></Sales><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/></Data_2><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <!-- Data 3 -->
                    <xsl:if test="$lineToken='3'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><Data_3><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="Sales" select="substring(., 2, 3)"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><xsl:value-of select="$tab"/><Sales><xsl:sequence select="$Sales"/></Sales><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/></Data_3><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                            <!-- Data 5 and Data 8 elements are identical -->
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Root>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I want to do is to be able to nest the data 2 and data 3 elements inside the summary element, but how do I process those lines and then start a new summary element for the next encountered 1 line?

I am sorry for all the generic stuff, I have a lot of data to work with and I am trying to simplify the question.
If more info is needed, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a job for `for-each-group group-starting-with` but in XSLT 2.0 you can only use that with sequences of nodes, not with sequences of strings. So I would first wrap the lines you get from the `tokenize(.,'\r?\n')` into an element e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="lines" as="element(line)*">
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\r?\n')">
    <line><xsl:value-of select="."/></line>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

then I would use

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$lines" group-starting-with="line[starts-with(., '1')]">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(self::line[starts-with(., '1')])">
      <!-- header -->
      <Header><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/></Header>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <Summary id="{substring(., 2)}">
         <!-- now use for-each select="if (position() eq last()) then current-group()[position() gt 1 and position() ne last()] else current-group()[position() gt 1]" or apply-templates to output the lines-->
        <xsl:for-each select="if (position() eq last()) then current-group()[position() gt 1 and position() ne last()] else current-group()[position() gt 1]">
          <xsl:element name="data_from_{substring(., 1, 1)}"><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/></xsl:element>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </Summary>
      <xsl:if test="position() eq last()">
        <Footer>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(current-group()[last()], 2)"/>
        </Footer>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

to group.

I have now found some time to write a working sample, the XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="text-url" select="'test2014032901.txt'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:variable name="text" select="unparsed-text($text-url)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="lines" as="element(line)*">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($text,'\r?\n')[normalize-space()]">
      <line><xsl:value-of select="."/></line>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <Root>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$lines" group-starting-with="line[starts-with(., '1')]">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(self::line[starts-with(., '1')])">
          <!-- header -->
          <xsl:variable name="periodStart" select="substring(., 2, 6)"/>
          <Header>
            <Period_start_date>
              <xsl:value-of select="$periodStart"/>
            </Period_start_date>
          </Header>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <Summary id="{substring(., 2, 11)}">
            <ID><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2, 11)"/></ID>
            <Batch_Date><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 13, 4)"/></Batch_Date>
            <!-- now use for-each select="if (position() eq last()) then current-group()[position() gt 1 and position() ne last()] else current-group()[position() gt 1]" or apply-templates to output the lines-->
            <xsl:for-each select="if (position() eq last()) then current-group()[position() gt 1 and position() ne last()] else current-group()[position() gt 1]">
              <xsl:element name="data_from_{substring(., 1, 1)}">
                <Sales>
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2, 3)"/>
                </Sales>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Summary>
          <xsl:if test="position() eq last()">
            <Footer>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(current-group()[last()], 2)"/>
            </Footer>
          </xsl:if>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </Root>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the name of the plain text file is passed in as the parameter `text-url` and the stylesheet is supposed to be started with `it:main` (template named `main` for Saxon)), then I get the result

```
<Root>
   <Header>
      <Period_start_date>xxxxxx</Period_start_date>
   </Header>
   <Summary id="xxxxxxxxxxx">
      <ID>xxxxxxxxxxx</ID>
      <Batch_Date>xxxx</Batch_Date>
      <data_from_2>
         <Sales>xxx</Sales>
      </data_from_2>
      <data_from_3>
         <Sales>xxx</Sales>
      </data_from_3>
      <data_from_5>
         <Sales>xxx</Sales>
      </data_from_5>
      <data_from_8>
         <Sales>xxx</Sales>
      </data_from_8>
   </Summary>
   <Summary id="xxxxxxxxxxx">
      <ID>xxxxxxxxxxx</ID>
      <Batch_Date>xxxx</Batch_Date>
      <data_from_2>
         <Sales>xxx</Sales>
      </data_from_2>
      <data_from_5>
         <Sales>xxx</Sales>
      </data_from_5>
      <data_from_8>
         <Sales>xxx</Sales>
      </data_from_8>
   </Summary>
   <Summary id="xxxxxxxxxxx">
      <ID>xxxxxxxxxxx</ID>
      <Batch_Date>xxxx</Batch_Date>
      <data_from_8>
         <Sales>xxx</Sales>
      </data_from_8>
   </Summary>
   <Footer>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Footer>
</Root>
```

Comment: I know the code you wrote is not tested, but I get an error that says `A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable $lines (&lt;line/&gt;, &lt;line/&gt;, ...)`. I am still new to XSL so I apologize if I don't understand the code fully.

Comment: Sorry, the type declaration of the variable lacked an `*`, I have corrected that.

Comment: @RXC, I have edited the answer with a complete code sample that you should be able to adapt to your needs more easily than the previous suggestion.